# How can use array_unique function in stdClass Object Array PHP

Tags: php, html

Im trying to get a unique array but I can't, because I am working with a stdClass Object. My object is named `$items` and it has duplicate values. Some part of it is below.

How can we do unique array this with php?

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [product_id] => 93 [model] => VNA452E1 [sku] => [upc] => [ean] => [jan] => [isbn] => [mpn] => [location] => [quantity] => 1 [stock_status_id] => 5 [image] => data/1NI_FD_245430_VNA453E1_4_Particolari_BIG.jpg [manufacturer_id] => 0 [shipping] => 1 [price] => 140.0000 [points] => 0 [tax_class_id] => 0 [date_available] => 2014-07-22 [weight] => 0.00000000 [weight_class_id] => 1 [length] => 0.00000000 [width] => 0.00000000 [height] => 0.00000000 [length_class_id] => 1 [subtract] => 1 [minimum] => 1 [sort_order] => 1 [status] => 1 [date_added] => 2014-07-23 16:14:26 [date_modified] => 2014-07-23 16:54:52 [viewed] => 9 [language_id] => 2 [name] => NIKON COOLPIX S02 [description] => <p><span style="font-size: 12pt;"><b>SENSORE</b>:CMOS, 1/3.1, Megapixel Reali : 14,17 , Megapixel Effettivi : 13,20 ; </span></p> <p><span style="font-size: 12pt;"><b>OBIETTIVO</b>: Zoom Ottico : 3 x, Zoom Digitale : 4 x, Apertura Max alla Focale Min : 3,30 F, Apertura Max alla Focale Max : 5,90 F; </span></p> <p><span style="font-size: 12pt;"><b>DISPLAY</b>:2,63 inches; </span></p> <p><span style="font-size: 12pt;"><b>OTTURATORE</b>:1, 1/2000; </span></p> <p><span style="font-size: 12pt;"><b>MEMORIA</b>:7300 mb; </span></p> <p><span style="font-size: 12pt;"><b>REGISTRAZIONE</b>:Risoluzione Max Immagine Foto (Larghezza) : 4160 , Risoluzione Max Immagine Foto </span></p> <p><span style="font-size: 12pt;">(Altezza) : 3120 , Registrazione HD; </span></p> <p><span style="font-size: 12pt;"><b>CONNESSIONI</b>:Connessione HDMI; </span></p> <p><span style="font-size: 12pt;"><b>ALTRE CARATTERISTICHE</b>:Microfono Incorporato, Adattabilità Treppiedi Standard; </span></p> <p><span style="font-size: 12pt;"><b>PESI E MISURE</b>:Altezza : 5,13 cm, Larghezza : 7,71 cm, Profondità : 1,75 cm, 100 g; </span></p> <p><span style="font-size: 12pt;"><b>GARANZIA</b>: 24 mesi.</span></p> <p><br /><br /></p> <p><br /><br /><br /></p> [meta_description] => [meta_keyword] => NIKON COOLPIX S02 [tag] => [category_name] => Cameras [category_id] => 33 ) 

[1] => stdClass Object ( [product_id] => 93 [model] => VNA452E1 [sku] => [upc] => [ean] => [jan] => [isbn] => [mpn] => [location] => [quantity] => 1 [stock_status_id] => 5 [image] => data/1NI_FD_245430_VNA453E1_4_Particolari_BIG.jpg [manufacturer_id] => 0 [shipping] => 1 [price] => 140.0000 [points] => 0 [tax_class_id] => 0 [date_available] => 2014-07-22 [weight] => 0.00000000 [weight_class_id] => 1 [length] => 0.00000000 [width] => 0.00000000 [height] => 0.00000000 [length_class_id] => 1 [subtract] => 1 [minimum] => 1 [sort_order] => 1 [status] => 1 [date_added] => 2014-07-23 16:14:26 [date_modified] => 2014-07-23 16:54:52 [viewed] => 9 [language_id] => 2 [name] => NIKON COOLPIX S02 [description] => <p><span style="font-size: 12pt;"><b>SENSORE</b>:CMOS, 1/3.1, Megapixel Reali : 14,17 , Megapixel Effettivi : 13,20 ; </span></p> <p><span style="font-size: 12pt;"><b>OBIETTIVO</b>: Zoom Ottico : 3 x, Zoom Digitale : 4 x, Apertura Max alla Focale Min : 3,30 F, Apertura Max alla Focale Max : 5,90 F; </span></p> <p><span style="font-size: 12pt;"><b>DISPLAY</b>:2,63 inches; </span></p> <p><span style="font-size: 12pt;"><b>OTTURATORE</b>:1, 1/2000; </span></p> <p><span style="font-size: 12pt;"><b>MEMORIA</b>:7300 mb; </span></p> <p><span style="font-size: 12pt;"><b>REGISTRAZIONE</b>:Risoluzione Max Immagine Foto (Larghezza) : 4160 , Risoluzione Max Immagine Foto </span></p> <p><span style="font-size: 12pt;">(Altezza) : 3120 , Registrazione HD; </span></p> <p><span style="font-size: 12pt;"><b>CONNESSIONI</b>:Connessione HDMI; </span></p> <p><span style="font-size: 12pt;"><b>ALTRE CARATTERISTICHE</b>:Microfono Incorporato, Adattabilità Treppiedi Standard; </span></p> <p><span style="font-size: 12pt;"><b>PESI E MISURE</b>:Altezza : 5,13 cm, Larghezza : 7,71 cm, Profondità : 1,75 cm, 100 g; </span></p> <p><span style="font-size: 12pt;"><b>GARANZIA</b>: 24 mesi.</span></p> <p><br /><br /></p> <p><br /><br /><br /></p> [meta_description] => [meta_keyword] => NIKON COOLPIX S02 [tag] => [category_name] => Fotocamere [category_id] => 33 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [product_id] => 92 [model] => 1FA6_002 [sku] => [upc] => [ean] => [jan] => [isbn] => [mpn] => [location] => [quantity] => 1 [stock_status_id] => 5 [image] => data/TOM_RG_216169_1FA4_002_02.jpg [manufacturer_id] => 0 [shipping] => 1 [price] => 259.0000 [points] => 0 [tax_class_id] => 0 [date_available] => 2014-07-22 [weight] => 0.00000000 [weight_class_id] => 1 [length] => 0.00000000 [width] => 0.00000000 [height] => 0.00000000 [length_class_id] => 1 [subtract] => 1 [minimum] => 1 [sort_order] => 1 [status] => 1 [date_added] => 2014-07-23 15:55:05 [date_modified] => 2014-07-23 15:58:36 [viewed] => 7 [language_id] => 2 [name] => TOM TOM GO 600 [description] => <p><span style="font-size: 14pt;"><b>SISTEMA GPS</b>:Auto; </span></p> <p><span style="font-size: 14pt;"><b>CARATTERISTICHE GENERALI</b>:Tom Tom, Italia, Austria - Svizzera - Germania, Francia, </span></p> <p><span style="font-size: 14pt;">Penisola Iberica, Regno Unito, Scandinavia, Paesi Est, Russia, Grecia, Major Roads Europe; </span></p> <p><span style="font-size: 14pt;"><b>SCHERMO</b>: 6 "Retroilluminazione, Visualizzazione 3D, 480 Pixels, Risoluzione Verticale 272, </span></p> <p><span style="font-size: 14pt;">Touchscreen; </span></p> <p><span style="font-size: 14pt;"><b>ESPANSIONE / CONNETTIVITÀ</b>:Canali : 12 , POI; </span></p> <p><span style="font-size: 14pt;"><b>CONNETTIVITÀ</b>:Bluetooth;</span></p> <p><span style="font-size: 14pt;"> <b>BATTERIA</b>:120 min; </span></p> <p><span style="font-size: 14pt;"><b>GARANZIA</b>: 24 mesi.</span></p> <p><br /><br /><br /><br /></p> [meta_description] => [meta_keyword] => TOM TOM GO 600 [tag] => [category_name] => Navigatori Satellitari [category_id] => 53 )
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can remove duplicate objects like this:

```
$array = array_map('json_encode', $array);
$array = array_unique($array);
$array = array_map('json_decode', $array);
```

[`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) is a function in php where you can apply a function (in this case [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)) to each value in the array. So every `stdClass Object` in your array is encoded in a JSON string. [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) then filters every value in the array and removes any duplicates. In your case the objects where probably not 100% duplicated but contained minor differences and you probably should use the next method. Then we apply the same trick but with [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to revert the JSON string to an object. You can also use [`serialize`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [`unserialize`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) for encoding and decoding the object from/to a string.

---

In case you to remove the objects with, for example, the same `product_id` you can do it this way.

```
$_tmp = array();
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if(!array_key_exists($value->product_id),$_tmp) {
        $_tmp [$value->product_id] = $value;
    }
}
$array = array_values($_tmp);
```

First we create an empty array, in this case `$_tmp` (derived from temporary, because we don't need it afterwards). Then we loop thru the array. With [`array_key_exists`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) we check if a key (`$value->product_id`) is **not** set in the array (`$_tmp`). Then we set assign the object to the key with the product_id. So if there is another object with the same product_id, it won't be added to the `$_tmp` array. The last line is assigning the object to the `$array` with [`array_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) so the keys are reset.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.I tried the first code , it doesnt work.And I couldnt see that where comes from $result in second code?

Comment: Yeah i forgot to save the return value of `array_unique`. The `$result` var was a bug cause i changed the name of the var in my head... silly me

Comment: I appreciate your effort. But I tried the your last code.And it doesnt works too.Are you missing anything in code ? Can you check it again?

Comment: Sorry @Ties. Your second solution works perfectly.Thanks a lot. God Bless You :)

Comment: But can you explain your code. I couldnt understand

Comment: Here you go. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

This might work - $array = (array) $object;