# remove duplicates values from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which looks like-

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [post_date] => 2017-01-04 14:28:00
    )

    [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [post_date] => 2017-01-05 11:06:00
    )

    [2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [post_date] => 2017-02-04 14:28:00
    )

    [3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [post_date] => 2017-02-04 14:34:00
    )
)
```

I used substr() function to get particular part-

```
foreach($unique_dates as $val) { 
    $year=substr($val->post_date,0,4);
    $month=substr($val->post_date,5,2);
    $monthName = date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 10)); 
    echo $monthName." ".$year."<br>";
}
```

Now It is showing output like -

```
January 2017  
January 2017  
February 2017  
February 2017
```

But I want Output like -

```
 January 2017  
February 2017
```

I tried as follows but didn't get proper output-

```
$unique_dates = array_map(
                    'unserialize',
                     array_unique(
                         array_map(
                             'serialize',
                             $dates
                         )
                     )
                );
```

I want to remove duplicates values.
How is this possible?
Thanks.

Comment: give it a try http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: So this will be your array to make unique right ? $monthName." ".$year

Comment: @VforVendetta yeah right

Comment: $arr = [
            "January 2017","January 2017","February 2017","February 2017"
            ];
            print_r(array_unique($arr)); This is simple answer then, but I think you want something different

Comment: as @VforVendetta said, array_unique is working as you asked deepak... `Array ( [0] => January 2017 [2] => February 2017 )` this is the o/p I got

Comment: if you reindex output then, array_values(array_unique($arr)); thats it, but is that what you want ?

Comment: The question is not the same but you should get the answer over this post following the advice of @xFighter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25087458/how-can-use-array-unique-function-in-stdclass-object-array-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run it like this:

```
foreach($unique_dates as $val) { 
    $year=substr($val->post_date,0,4);
    $month=substr($val->post_date,5,2);
    $monthName = date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 10)); 
    $result[] = $monthName." ".$year;
} 
$result = array_flip($result); // here will remove the duplicate value, and return as the keys of the array.
array_walk($results, function($v, $k){echo $k.'<br>';});
```

Comment: @ Kris sorry for late reply. This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks for help.